# Is it possible to set Details for Overloaded method in .net?

Tags: .net, oop, visual-studio-2013

[image]

i want to add some description such as  .net methods overload   is it possible or not?

Answer (score 5):

What you are referring to is [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)